# Symfony 5.3 How to return a JSON response from a Before Filter (EventSubscriberInterface) and set Variable to access in Controller?

Tags: symfony5

I am creating an API and would like to do a few checks for every single Endpoint, so I decided that it needs to go somewhere central to not duplicate any code. I have created a Event Subscriber. Question now, how can I return the JSON response to the API bypassing the controller, when the try catch fails and second, how can I pass on the variable $confirm to the controller when it succeeded? Is that achievable?

**UPDATE**
It is now working and I figured out the other bit myself. I have updated the Sourcecode with the changes, in case somebody else needs it (check the UPDATE comment). I hope this is the correct Symfony approach as well even if it's working. Thank you again to Rova Ram !

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Controller\ApiCheckController;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


class ApiSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
       $this->em = $em;
       
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        // UPDATE add below line
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // when a controller class defines multiple action methods, the controller
        // is returned as [$controllerInstance, 'methodName']
        if (is_array($controller)) {
            $controller = $controller[0];
        }
        
        if ($controller instanceof \App\Controller\ApiCheckController) {
         
            try {
                $confirm = $this->confirmRequest($someData);

                // UPDATE add below this way confirm will be available 
                // in the Controller via  $confirm= $request->get('confirm');
                $request->attributes->set('confirm', $confirm );

            }
            catch(\Exception $e) {
                 $payload = array(
                    "status" => "error", 
                    "message" => $e->getMessage(),
                );

        // UPDATE replace below
        // return new JsonResponse($payload,  JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            
        // instead use
       return $event->setController( function () use($payload) {
                        return new JsonResponse($payload,  JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
                    } ); 
      }

      public static function getSubscribedEvents()
      {
        return [
          KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController'
      
        ];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returnin your JSON response like this

```
$event->setController( function () use () {
                            return new JsonResponse();
                        } );
```